# Get signal SIGABRT

Tags: c++, c

I' m trying to understad the work with a pointers. So I've wrote a test program  where name is split into labels by removing the separating dots.  Each label is represented as a length/data pair as follows:
google.ru represents as "x\06googlex\02ru"
I get signal SIGABRT when i returned from my test function
I guess it's caused with my bad work with pointer.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
void test(unsigned char* dns, unsigned char* host);

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    unsigned char host[]="google.ru";

    unsigned char* dnsTest=(unsigned char*)malloc(20);

    if(dnsTest==NULL)
    {
        exit(1);
    }

    test(dnsTest, host);

    printf("%s", dnsTest);

    free(dnsTest);


    return 0;
}
void test(unsigned char* dns, unsigned char* host)
{
    strcat((char*)host, ".");

    int lock=0;

    for(int i=0; i<strlen((char *)host);i++)
    {
        if(host[i]=='.')
        {

            *dns=i-lock;

            dns++;

            for(;lock<i; lock++)
            {
                *dns=host[lock];
                dns++;

            }
                lock++;
        }
    }
    *dns='\0';

}
```

Comment: `strcat((char*)host, ".");` - buffer overflow

Comment: @melpomene: it's either C99 or C++, but it doesn't really matter for that question.

Comment: Don't cast `malloc()`. It's not needed and can hide errors.

Comment: Don't use `malloc`; prefer `std::string` or `std::vector<unsigned char>` or whatever.

Comment: `1` is not a portable exit code. Use `EXIT_FAILURE` instead.

Comment: Don't use C-style casts; use `static_cast<>` where possible (or preferably restructure your code so no casts are needed).

Comment: Use `size_t` for your index variables, not `int`. Calling `strlen(host)` in each loop iteration is wasteful.

Answer (score 0):

Since you tagged c++ as well, you can use `new \ delete` instead of `malloc \ free`. `New` will call constructor (when you will learn classes it will be useful), and `new` return to you exact type, so no need to cast (and casting is almost always a bad idea)

Then assertion after memory allocation with `new` will be redundant:

```
if(dnsTest==NULL)
```

since c++ `new` will throw an exception by default.
If you go ahead, you can use `std::string` - its much more simple than c null terminated strings (but not for the task of understanding pointers).

Every other comments (about redundant `strlen` usage and absence of `'\0'` symbol) is correct too, but I want to give you two advices, how to grasp pointers.

First - read [K&R](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131103628) - it's the Bible.

Second - if you use Microsoft Visual Studio, you can compile your code in Debug mode, and use Memory View tab. Visual Studio compiler place some magic number inside memory ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127386/in-visual-studio-c-what-are-the-memory-allocation-representations)) at debug mode. They can help you with understanding where you addressing unallocated memory or how exactly your memory layout looks like.